# Jquery selector not with wildcard

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a Jquery selector `'a[href!="#"][href!="javascript:;"][href]'` for `$(document).on(clickEvent, "<selector>")`. I want to add to this selector a action for my href DOES NOT end with "/download/".
I want to make use of Jquery wildcard selector, something like Negation of the following :

```
$("[href$='/download/']")
```

This means href ending with "/download/". But, I did not find any way to do "Not ending with" using the same selector.

Comment: At this point, assuming this isn't an XY problem (a sound design usually prevents the need to do this kind of selection), I would use `filter`.

Comment: Or even a plain `if ($(evt.target).attr('href').endsWith('/download/')) return;` in your event handler. You don't need to make a perfect selector.

Comment: "I was able to achieve the same using `href:not(:contains("/download/"))`" Are you sure about that? That seems like a nonsensical selector.

Comment: @BoltClock : Yes, it works. I am using it as a selector in $(document).on(clickEvent,[selector])

Comment: did any of the answers help?

Comment: No, nothing worked. Only what @Amadan commented worked. I had to use if($(evt.target).attr('href').indexOf('/download/') != -1) return;

Answer (score 1):

You could try with something like

```
$("a").not("[href*='download']")
```

Answer (score 1):

here is one way:-

```
$('a:not([href$="/download/"])')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using bellow.

```
$(':not([href$="/download/"])')
```

Edit: alternatively

```
$(selector).not('[href$="/download/"]');
```